# batch get drivename mounted iso

Tags: batch-file

I have iso files to mount. How can set the Name from listing to set in a Variable?

Example Mounted in x:

```
X:\>dir
Datenträger in Laufwerk X: ist Running one file
```

how can set

```
Running one file
```

in a variable?

Comment: You can use the `FOR /F` command to capture the output of another command.

Comment: @Squashman, use a simple `for` loop with a wildcard set, which stays within the current shell and works with Unicode filenames. In contrast, a `/f` loop with a command reads a piped output byte stream from a child process, which CMD decodes line-by-line using the current console codepage. A subshell (e.g. for running `'dir'`) does use this codepage (unless using `cmd /u /c`,  which outputs UTF-16 to a pipe), so that at least matches up. However, characters that aren't in this extremely limited set will be translated to best-fit characters (e.g. "ÀÁÂÃ" -> "AAAA" in CP 437) and question marks.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the output with:

```
for /f "tokens=5,*" %%a in ('vol C:') do echo %%b
```

but it's better to use a language independent solution, like:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where Caption^="C:" get volumename /value') do for /f "delims=" %b in ("%%a") do set "name=%%b"
```